Forwarding WebRTC traffice through Ubuntu Device
I am trying to connect to a WebRTC stream through an ubuntu device. The ubuntu device is connected to my PC on one of its nics (PC ip = 12.2.20.3, Ubuntu ip = 12.2.20.58) and the external device hosting the WebRTC Service (Ubuntu ip = 10.0.0.58, external device = 10.0.0.3).
If I set up my PC connection directly I can connect over port 31102 and recieve the stream in my browser.
Any help would be appreciated to figure out how to forward this stream through the two network interfaces on the Ubuntu machine (running 20.04).
Judging from documentation I need to forward all ports from 31000-32000.
